# Use UI library mixins in custom module

Tags: magento2, less, ui-library

I need to use some UI components in a custom module, so I included Magento2 Ui base library in my less file in this way:

```
@base-dir: "../../";
@import '@{base-dir}css/source/lib/_lib';
```

This works fine as long as my site is in *developer* mode. But when I push it to an instance in *production* mode and launch `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` it fails with this error:

`File ../../css/source/lib/_lib.less not found. in reseller.less`

There are a [couple](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3288) of [bug reports](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2264) that could to be related to this. Does anyone found a solution?

**Edit:**

As a workaround I manage to have it working by adding a symlink in my css folder to the lib folder and importing from there, so there are no more relative paths. But it is a very dirty way to accomplish what I need. I would like to see some better and cleaner solutions.

Answer (score 0):

In module you can call directly mixins from magento, You don't need import any files. Usually mixins of magento located in folder lib/web/css/source/lib
The only thing you can't is call variables and mixins defined in theme (call mixin from module). Instead you need define your variables/mixins inside _module.less (in your module) and use it later

path _module.less usually

`app/code/YourBrand/YourModuleName/view/area/web/css/source/_module.less`

area can frontend adminhtml or base.
Because you don't mention any area related adminhtml or frontend so i will assume frontend as default